# Parsing the time data from last command which has total "00:00" time spent on the last column

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have last command output for the hundred of Servers collected into the File,the problem is now is output is "Feb,Jan,Feb" meaning that its taking the Feb output of last years as well, So, i'm looking around the way if i can get the output With each Server name "Feb to Jan" and if it decedents the Feb again then ignore it as it will be for gone year (in my case 2016) where i'm looking for 2017 only. Because i am looking if any Server in have the time "(00:00)" in the last column for the entire period between "Feb to Jan" considering the above facts..

Below is the Data Format please advise your solution.
I have tagged awk,sed,shell because any of solution will work for me..

```
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Feb 16 16:12 - 16:12  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Feb 15 03:28 - 03:28  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Feb 15 03:27 - 03:27  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Feb 15 03:27 - 03:27  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Feb  6 18:36 - 18:36  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Feb  5 07:26 - 07:26  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Feb  5 07:26 - 07:26  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Feb  5 07:26 - 07:26  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan 28 04:16 - 04:16  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Jan 26 17:03 - 17:03  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Jan 26 17:03 - 17:03  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Jan 26 17:03 - 17:03  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Jan 18 08:07 - 08:07  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Jan 16 21:13 - 21:13  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Jan 16 21:13 - 21:13  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Jan 16 21:13 - 21:13  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Jan  8 18:33 - 18:33  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan  7 06:56 - 06:56  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan  7 06:56 - 06:56  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan  7 06:56 - 06:56  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod8] out: rocky pts/0        sojourner.padenc Fri Feb  5 09:08 - 11:08  (02:00)
[oraprod8] out: rocky pts/0        vlsj-rocky.pa Wed Feb  3 09:48 - 10:03  (00:14)
[oraprod8] out: rocky tty1                          Wed Feb  3 09:31 - 09:31  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Feb 16 16:12 - 16:12  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Feb 15 03:28 - 03:28  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Feb 15 03:27 - 03:27  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Feb 15 03:27 - 03:27  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Feb  6 18:36 - 18:36  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Feb  5 07:26 - 07:26  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Feb  5 07:26 - 07:26  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Feb  5 07:26 - 07:26  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan 28 04:16 - 04:16  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Jan 26 17:03 - 17:03  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Jan 26 17:03 - 17:03  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Thu Jan 26 17:03 - 17:03  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Wed Jan 18 08:07 - 08:07  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Jan 16 21:13 - 21:13  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Jan 16 21:13 - 21:13  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Mon Jan 16 21:13 - 21:13  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sun Jan  8 18:33 - 18:33  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan  7 06:56 - 06:56  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan  7 06:56 - 06:56  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        oratest.paden Sat Jan  7 06:56 - 06:56  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: root     pts/0        dbtest.pad Thu Feb 11 13:58 - 13:58  (00:00)
[oraprod7] out: rocky pts/0        sojourner.padenc Fri Feb  5 09:08 - 11:08  (02:00)
[oraprod7] out: rocky pts/0        vlsj-rocky.pa Wed Feb  3 09:48 - 10:03  (00:14)
[oraprod7] out: rocky tty1                          Wed Feb  3 09:31 - 09:31  (00:00)
```

Answer (score 0):

RMaaS: [`man last`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/last) :

> **`-F`**
>
> Print **full** login and logout times and dates.

And then filter out undesirable years...

```
last -F |grep " Feb " |grep -v " 2016 " 
herman   pts/0        52d94b85.cm-11   Tue Feb 21 15:15:13 2017   still logged in
herman   pts/0        52d94b85.cm-11   Mon Feb 20 14:24:10 2017 - Mon Feb 20 16:44:41 2017  (02:20)
herman   pts/0        52d94b85.cm-11   Sat Feb 18 14:12:36 2017 - Sat Feb 18 20:57:21 2017  (06:44)
herman   pts/0        52d94b85.cm-11   Wed Feb 15 11:20:45 2017 - Wed Feb 15 11:34:03 2017  (00:13)
herman   pts/0        52d94b85.cm-11   Tue Feb 14 13:26:28 2017 - Tue Feb 14 15:55:37 2017  (02:29)
herman   pts/0        52d94b85.cm-11   Mon Feb 13 13:07:59 2017 - Mon Feb 13 16:13:55 2017  (03:05)
....
herman   pts/0        d64-180-204-13   Sat Feb 23 17:54:16 2013 - Sat Feb 23 20:26:42 2013  (02:32)
herman   pts/0        d64-180-204-13   Wed Feb 20 04:49:02 2013 - Wed Feb 20 05:07:50 2013  (00:18)
herman   pts/0        d64-180-204-13   Thu Feb 14 09:05:39 2013 - Thu Feb 14 12:29:51 2013  (03:24)
herman   pts/0        d64-180-196-15   Sun Feb  3 17:36:00 2013 - Sun Feb  3 20:47:08 2013  (03:11)
```

Comment: Just forgot to mention  that i have mix of host list and `"last -F"` only works on certain Linux Flavors only, that's the reason i'm unable to get it that way.